# Is there a way to have an array that automatically grows like in PHP?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In PHP there is code like this:

```
<?php
 $myarray [] = "Hello";
 $myarray [] = "BOB";
for($i = 0; $i < count($myarray); $i++) echo $myarray[$i];
?>
```

Is there any code like this in Ruby-On-Rails?

Comment: ain't all the arrays dynamic in Ruby?

Comment: They may be. I am a newbie and from what I can see, it looks like it may try to get a size of the array.  What I am aiming for is not having to specify the size (like what is possible in PHP).

Comment: What, exactly, about that code do you want to replicate? Iterating over the array? Dynamically sized ones?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
strings << "Hello" << "BOB"
strings.each { |string| print string }
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays already automatically grow, nothing special needed. The Ruby equivalent would be:

```
list = []
list.push("Hello", "BOB")
list.each {|row| puts row}
```

This will print out "Hello" and "BOB" on their own lines.